# (PYTHON) TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

la idea del código es que lea un archivo .txt y cada linea la convierta en una lista. Luego cada valor de la lista obtenida lo tiene que buscar en otra lista y si no lo encuentra lo agrega. La traba esta cuando se ejecuta el if , me dice que el argumento no es iterable, pero si imprimo el argumento que le paso antes de que entre en el ultimo bucle for me lo imprime como lista, asique estoy confundida y no entiendo en que me estoy equivocando. Necesitaría una ayuda con esto, muchas gracias :)

```
romeo=open("romeo.txt")
lista_verif=["Arise","But","It","Juliet","Who","already","adn",
"breaks"]
for linea in romeo:
    lista_romeo=linea.split()
    #print(lista_romeo)
    for i in lista_romeo:

        if i not in lista_verif:
            lista_verif= lista_verif.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explicación

Cuando i no está en lista_verif, haces un append y le asignas el resultado de ese método (que sería None) a la variable lista_verif, reemplazando la lista que estaba guardada en la variable por None. Cuando el proceso se repite y ejecutas esta linea `if i not in lista_verif:`, es como hacer `if(i not in None)`. Y como sabemos, buscar algo dentro de nada no tiene sentido.

En pocas palabras, esta linea `lista_verif= lista_verif.append(i)` hace lo mismo que:

```
lista_verif.append(i)
lista_verif = None
```

#### Solucion

La solución es tan simple como cambiar esta linea `lista_verif= lista_verif.append(i)` por esta `lista_verif.append(i)`.

No necesitas asignar ningún valor a ninguna variable para que el elemento se añada a la lista. append añade un elemento a la lista, NO crea una lista nueva.